# Why is QOverload used to connect a signal and a slot?

Tags: qt, overloading, signals-slots, qtcpserver, qabstractsocket

I saw an example for running a ***TCP Server*** with Qt.

In this example a class named `Client` was created,  its constructor had 5 connections between signals and slots of `QTcpSocket` and `Client` class. In one of the connections this code was written:

```
connect(&socket,QOverload<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>::of(&QAbstractSocket::errorOccurred),this,&Client::error);
```

I am familiar with signal and slot mechanism and how to connect.

Now my questions are:

- What is the role of `of` in above code?
- According to `QAbstractSocket`'s `errorOccurred` signal, why do we use `QOverload`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do you saw it exactly? I think it's a leftover from QAbstractSocket::error -> QAbstractSocket::errorOccured changes. There were two functions called error (one getter and the signal) but the signal was deprecated and renamed to errorOccured. So the QOverload is no longer needed.

Comment: `QOverload<...>::of` uses template metaprogramming tricks to select a particular overload (the one whose parameter types are in the angle brackets) from a set of overloaded member functions. Sometimes a signal or a slot is overloaded (there are multiple signals with the same name, taking different parameter types), and then just passing `&ClassName::signalNam` leads to compiler error, as the compiler can't tell which overload you meant to pass. `QOverload<...>::of` is a convenient syntax to disambiguate.